# Canonical form to save irregular time series of matrices?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, zoo, tidyverse

Let's say a bunch of people `p` move a bunch of objects `o` around in a 2-dimensional grid of `i * k` (eventually, n-dimensional).

Whenever some `p` makes a move, I take a snapshot of the `i x k` grid (this actually happens via js callbacks).

So, for `p` `Alice` and `o`s `c("foo", "bar)`, and `i`, `k` of 2 each, at, say, `2017-12-24 18:00:00`, this gives something like

```
   1       2
1  "foo"     
2          "bar"
```

and, four seconds later, at `2017-12-26 18:00:04`, say,

```
   1       2
1  "foo"     
2  "bar"
```

For some other `p` `Bob`, I get similar snapshots, but, crucially *at different times*, because, well, `Bob` chooses to move objects at different times.

For most of the analysis, I will just look at the *final* (latest) snapshot for each `p`, and then happily `abind()` the whole thing in a `p x i x k` array.

But I *also* want to retain the irregularly ordered time series.
How **do I best store this data in a clever, canonical way in R**?

Since I can't `abind()` over the irregular time points (because they're all different per person), my **current approach** is to just put the snapshots in a list for each `p`, like, say,

```
data$alice <- list(
  `2017-12-24 18-00-00` = matrix(data = c("foo", NA, NA, "bar"), nrow = 2),
  `2017-12-24 18-00-04` = matrix(data = c("foo", NA, "bar", NA), nrow = 2))
data$bob <- ...
```

and so forth. (Perhaps, I'd rather use proper [lubricate](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org) `datetimes` as list element attributes, but that's details).

This works ok, but feels hacky/weird, for a number of reasons:

1. Lists do not natively support time series info, so adding them as list element attributes feels hacky.
2. The list makes it hard to see that *all* the individual matrices are of the same rank (as they must be). (I guess this is unavoidable, since I can't `abind()` meaningfully).
3. My intuitive ideas are usually bad. There just has to be a better way.

I'm new to time series, and I just want to make sure that I'm not being very stupid and (poorly) reinventing the wheel to a canonically solved problem here.
Also: this is going to be part of a package, and an `S3` class, so I want to get this right.

---

Caveats / Asides:

- I have looked into the [zoo](http://zoo.r-forge.r-project.org) package, but while that offers *irregular* time intervals (which I have), it doesn't seem to offer a class for *different* irregular time intervals.
- I don't want to store this data in a tidy format. I'm with [Jeff Leek](https://simplystatistics.org/2016/02/17/non-tidy-data/) here; the matrix representation of the grids is inherently meaningful, and I want to retain that. There will also be some matrix algebra, and that would just make for really opaque code, if applied to tidy data. That said, if I'm being stupid here, and the canonical way to store this kind of data in tidy form, I'm open to it.

Ps.: Apologies for the shameless pseudo-code/math. Hope it still helps to make things clearer.

Comment: Have you looked at `xts`? I must admit I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, except extending the time series format, and that's sort of what `xts` is all about.

Comment: Can Alice and Bob both have the same time in their list or are times globally unique?  Do all matrices across the entire structure have the same dimensions?

Comment: Alice and Bob may, by accident, have the same times in their list. The matrices across the entire structure have the same dimensions @G. Grothendieck.

Comment: I *have* looked at `xts` @AkselA, though I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with these irregular time series, which are different for each `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions, although I don't know if they are "canonical." You can either use a `pdata.frame` (from the `plm` package for panel data) or a `tibble`.

Setting up some data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  person = c("Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob"),
  time = as.POSIXct(runif(4, 1500000000, 1510000000), origin = "1970-01-01")
)
mats <- lapply(1:4, function(...) matrix(sample(1:4, 4), nc = 2, nr = 2))
```

The `pdata.frame` approach stores each matrix element as a column, which would give you `i * k` columns in addition to person and time identifiers.

```
library(plm)
dat_plm <- cbind(dat, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mats, as.vector))))
pdat <- pdata.frame(dat_plm, index = c("person", "time"), row.names = FALSE)
pdat
#   person                time V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  Alice 2017-08-04 05:52:13  1  3  2  4
# 2  Alice 2017-08-26 08:13:42  2  4  3  1
# 4    Bob 2017-08-09 08:45:14  4  3  1  2
# 3    Bob 2017-10-28 11:20:55  1  3  2  4
str(pdat)
# Classes ‘pdata.frame’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ person: Factor w/ 2 levels "Alice","Bob": 1 1 2 2
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "4" "3"
#   ..- attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ person: Factor w/ 2 levels "Alice","Bob": 1 1 2 2
#   .. ..$ time  : Factor w/ 4 levels "2017-08-04 05:52:13",..: 1 3 2 4
# <snip>
#  - attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ person: Factor w/ 2 levels "Alice","Bob": 1 1 2 2
#   ..$ time  : Factor w/ 4 levels "2017-08-04 05:52:13",..: 1 3 2 4
```

The `tibble` to me is more elegant:

```
library(tibble)
dat_tbl <- as_tibble(dat)
dat_tbl$mats <- mats
dat_tbl
#   person                time          mats
#   <fctr>              <dttm>        <list>
# 1  Alice 2017-08-04 05:52:13 <int [2 x 2]>
# 2  Alice 2017-08-26 08:13:42 <int [2 x 2]>
# 3    Bob 2017-10-28 11:20:55 <int [2 x 2]>
# 4    Bob 2017-08-09 08:45:14 <int [2 x 2]>
```

It allows you, for example, to take the most recent snapshot for each individual:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(dat_tbl, time) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  slice(n())
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   person [2]
#   person                time          mats
#   <fctr>              <dttm>        <list>
# 1  Alice 2017-08-26 08:13:42 <int [2 x 2]>
# 2    Bob 2017-10-28 11:20:55 <int [2 x 2]>
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might want to mention that the `tibble` recommendation is purely political. `dat$mats <- mats` works just as well.